# Community Wiki -- Where is it?

Tags: support, community-wiki

I've seen numerous questions answered with comments in the form "This should be a community-wiki question".  This seems to imply that there is a list of such "community-wiki" questions somewhere.

Is there a such a list available?  If so, where is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Community Wiki *was* an option that was quickly deprecated - questions and answers flagged as Community Wiki earned no reputation, and could be edited by anybody. In some cases, the suggestion that something should be community-wiki is an indication that the question is a bit too subjective to fit the Stack Exchange idea of answering questions with definitive answers.

Now that all questions and answers can be edited by anybody (albeit with peer review for lower reputation users), the feature is no longer required.

Comment: Community wiki is still around. This blog post does a good job describing what it can/should be used for still: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/

Answer (score 2):

You can still mark an *answer* as community wiki, which you might do when you want to not have personal ownership of a particular answer — perhaps it is a summary of other answers, or a bit of dry factual information you don't think deserves individual credit, or maybe it's an answer you know to be incomplete and hope someone else will fill out.

Here, I've done it for no good reason at all except to demonstrate. :)